# Alternative for static variable in abstract supeclass

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, static

I'm trying to have an abstract superclass `Race` that is implemented by my ants as generic so that I can access attributes like "Movement Speed" for the ants. For the different races I will create classes extending `Race` and I want to give each `Race` different attributes, obviously. "Movement Speed" needs to be static in `Race` somehow so I can access them by the Class and not an instance of the object but it can't be static because then its the same for all races. I need a way to circumvent this problem because my whole program structure relies on it.

I can't make `Race` be the superclass of `Ant` because I have subclasses of `Ant` like `Drone` or `Queen` and they should be accessible for all races.

```
public abstract class Race {
    public static double speed;
}

public class defaultAnt extends Race {
    public static double speed = 2;
}

public abstract class Ant<R extends Race> {
    public void move(){
           speed = R.speed;
    }
}
```

When I try it like this its all the same for all races, though it shouldn't be.

Comment: `static` fields are bound to classes and not instances of those classes.

Comment: Hi! When you were asking your question, there was a big **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful info in it. There was also a toolbar full of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area showing what your post would look like when posted, located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to get you to look at it). Making your post clear, and showing that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers. I've fixed it for you this time.

Comment: I just gave a vague hint in my answer what you should do instead of using static here. Problem is: to give a better answer, I would have to understand your question better. It starts with: do you mean "race" like "species", or do you mean "race" like "racing contest"?

Comment: I know what static means and I see the problem, I was looking for ideas how to solve the problem and with race I mean species, I thought that was more obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Movement Speed" needs to be static in Race somehow so I can access them by the Class

Not at all. Consider `static` to be an abnormality in good OOP design, especially in Java. The OOP way would be to go like this:

```
public abstract class Race {
  protected abstract double getIndividualSpeed();
...
```

and then subclasses (in the right place) @Override that to provide individual speed.

But as said: the key thing here is that you step back and re-think your design. Using a static field, especially in a "polymorphic" context is (almost) a no-go.

Beyond that, that idea about generics, it doesn't fit here too good. Generics are (more or less) about "containing" something. When you say `class Foo<T extends Bar>` then you communicate that Foo instances will somehow own/relate to the Bar class. Which, yes somehow fits your usecase, but (personally), I am not sure if generics are the right choice here.

And the thing is: generics are mostly a **compile time** thing. At runtime, that notion of `R` is **gone**. Your class `Ant` has no knowledge whether you had

```
Ant<Drone> ant = new Ant...
```

or

```
Ant<Queen> a2 = ...
```

In other words: `R.speed` is not possible conceptually. A more OOP approach could look like this:

```
public abstract class BaseAnt<R extends Race> {
   protected final R rInstance;
   protected BaseAnt(R rInstance) { this.R rInstance = R rInstance; }

   public final double move(double distance) {
      return distance / Instance.getSpeed();
   }

public class Ant<R extends Race> {
  ctor that calls super constructor
```

and then

```
public enum Race {
  DRONE(5), QUEEN(1);

  private final double speed;
  private Race(double speed) { this.speed = speed; }

  public double getSpeed() { return speed; }
```

In other words: you can use an **enum** that works as "constant provider". You can invoke `getSpeed()` on Race.DRONE; and you get back `5` then.

And then you can instantiate Ants using either Race.DRONE or Race.QUEEN.

The BaseAnt class on the other hand does all the "common" stuff for Ants, and your child classes then add specific behavior.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I didnt know that I should avoid statics in OOP. I thought about Race being an object that every ant has an instance of, but my entire design revolves around this system and so I thought maybe Im missing something and I could get the solution here. And to be honest I was kinda happy that I (more or less) understood the generics and used them :D

Comment: @Pht The point is: you have to be careful about using static. It leads to direct coupling to other classes, and it has different "semantics" regarding polymorphism.

Comment: I always have a "Properties" class which is abstract and only contains static final variables, for example frame sizes. I use this so I dont have to go searching in my code when I want to change something so fundamental. I thought I could do it similarily but apparently thats not the case^^

Comment: Oh wow yes, thank you so much for your detailed answer and your time!

Comment: @Pht I appreciate the quick comeback. If you have a second, please look through your comments and see if some of them can be deleted. The idea is to leave only content that is really helpful for  future readers, so that they can focus ... well, on the helpful stuff.